# Can someone explain this sample PHP code for me?

Tags: php, html

I am doing my independent study on PHP and HTML in w3school and I don't understand the following codes: (copied from the w3school)

```
1  <!DOCTYPE html>
2  <html>
3  <body>
4
5  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
6    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
7    <input type="submit">
8  </form>
9
10 <?php
11 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
12     // collect value of input field
13     $name = $_POST['fname']; 
14     if (empty($name)) {
15         echo "Name is empty";
16     } else {
17         echo $name;
18     }
19 }
20 ?>
21 
22 </body>
23 </html>
```

Q1: Why can I, and how should I insert a PHP code in the middle of a bunch of HTML codes like what the sample did in line 5? What topic should I look at to learn more about this kind of operation?

Q2: In the PHP codes after line 10, why would I want to include a if statement to decide if the request method is "POST"? Can't I just go to the other if condition, as in the one to check it the text box is empty?

Appreciate your help(:

Comment: You can insert a php code opening with <?php closing with ?> anywhere in the html document.

Comment: where did you copy the code from?

Comment: As I stated, I copied this from the w3school.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal Thanks. I have overlooked that. Could you explain why is it written in that way?

Comment: @YuyangHuang why is it written inside the double quotes?  You can interpret that the same way as `action=<?php echo '"'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"';?>"`, if the filename you're working on is `index.php` the output will be: `action="index.php"`. But you can start writing <?php ?> codes inside the double quotes (it is easier to interpret it that way

Comment: @YuyangHuang as for your Q2, if you do not check the `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` the code inside it will be executed even when you have not submitted the form

Comment: @YuyangHuang i read that but *where* on w3schools? what url? there is lots of code there on many pages

Comment: @Memor-X http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Answer (score 0):

Answer of question 1:

- You can add your php code anywhere in the HTML document. You have to use `<?php` to start and `?>` to end.

Answer of question 2:

- You have to include an if statement to decide the request is POST because you have given POST method in your form. You can learn more about form and its attributes from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_forms.htm)
- You have to write your PHP code in this page because you have mentioned `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in the action attribute which means that all your form data will be sent to this(self) page through POST method.
  -You can learn about method from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)